# Failed to import Jquery date value in asp.net text box

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, webforms, textbox

I have a created a jquery component over asp.net web forms, Its a date picker and in view state I can select my date , but I failed to export my date to my text box.
Below is the code of my component I included "date-time-picker.inc"

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >

      <script src="datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
      <input id="datetimepicker1" type="text" />
      <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
              lang: 'en',
              i18n: {
                  en: {
                      months: [
                     'January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
                     'May', 'June', 'July', 'August',
                     'September', 'October', 'November', 'December',
                         ],
                      dayOfWeek: [
                      "Su.", "Mo", "Tu", "We",
                      "Th", "Fr", "Sa.",
                        ]

                        }
                          },
              timepicker: false,
              format: 'd-m-Y',
              maxDate: '-1970/01/01',
              defaultDate:'true',
              defaultSelect:'true',
              startDate: new Date()

          });
```

and this is my aspx page looks like

```
  <label><img src="images1/datetime.jpg" /></label>
            <% 
                Response.WriteFile("components/date-time-picker.inc");
            %>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ReadOnly = "true"></asp:TextBox>
```

I tried to put my textbox ID into JQuery("[id$=txtDate]").datetimepicker but then my component get disabled. Can anybody help me which is the best way to export value from jquery into asp.net textbox so I can further process it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have 2 input fields I See, `txtDate` and `datetimepicker1`. If you select a date does it get displayed into the `datetimepicker1` field? If so why do you want to set it to `txtDate`? You can make your `datetimepicker1` as a ASP.NET TextBox to catch the value in your codebehind.

Comment: @VDesign Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input element as a ASP.NET control:

Change this:

```
<input id="datetimepicker1" type="text" />
```

Into this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="datetimepicker1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then your JS code ( selector possible in multiple ways ):

*Here I ask to take the input element where the ID ends with `$=` datetimepicker1 because if you use masterpages there will be a prefix.*

```
    jQuery('input[id$=datetimepicker1]').datetimepicker({
       // code

    });
```